# In convert case, what is the difference between blend and normal version?

Tags: notepad++, string-manipulation

In notepad++, if you go to `Edit` > `Convert Case to`, you have entries like:

- `Proper Case`
- `Proper Case (blend)`
- `Sentence case`
- `Sentence case (blend)`

What is the difference between `blend` and `"normal"` version ?

[image: cases illustration]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The **Proper Case** command UPPER-cases the first letter of each word and LOWER-cases all the other letters of each word
- The **Proper Case (blend)** command UPPER-cases the first letter of each word and does NOT change the case of all the other letters of each word
- The **Sentence case** command UPPER-cases the first letter of each sentence and LOWER-cases all the other letters of each sentence
- The **Sentence case (blend)** command UPPER-cases the first letter of each sentence and does NOT change the case of all the other letters of each sentence

Comment: Very clear. Thank you!!